# Is it possible to configure a machine wide WinRM client default authentication?

Tags: powershell, authentication, remote-access, winrm

WinRM is the protocol used by Windows Machine when running remote commands, WinRM supports several authentication schemes.

Is there a machine wide setting to control the default authentication mechanism used by the `Invoke-Command` commandlet when executing commands on a remote host?

I would like to have the Authentication defaulting to the `Basic` authentication scheme without having to use the `-Authentication` parameter.

**Is this possible, or does it have to be specified explicitly when invoking the command?**